# MVC Retaining Model binding with simple Datatable client side pageination

Tags: model-view-controller, model, datatables

I have a model which contains a list of items.
The list will have no more than 100 items.
Hence, I grab this list in one hit when I grab the model.

I want to be able to create / edit this model in a view that has pageination on it.

If I have for instance 20 items in my list and a page size of 5 I see 4 pages.  I find that when editting on any page other than 1 my models list comes though to the Action as null.
If I am on page 1, the models list only has 5 items.

I understand why this is, but I cannot figure out how to get round this without posting my model in chunks.

Is there a way I can do what I want, which is to post the model in 1 hit from a view that has pageination on it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on the downvote - but I seem to have got there in the end.

I call this function to expand the table to show all rows before submitting.....

```
function expandTable() {
    var oTable = $('#tblCategories').DataTable();
    oTable.page.len(250).draw();
};
```

.....my model makes it through to the action intact with ALL of the list items present.